# How do I know if service is completed?

Tags: ros, action-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running service client method with 1 server and 4 clients. I am running 5 different programs for them. I need to first send data from client1 to server and call for service. After this service is completed, I need to initialise other service with client3 and client4. How do I achieve this? How do I make client3 and client4 call a service after the client2 has finished the service? What I am trying to do is:

1. Client2 sends data to Server.
2. Server distributes that data among Client2, Client3 and Client4.
3. Client2, Client3, Client4 returns back their data to server after processing.
4. Server then reorganizes all data and returns final result to Client2.

The main problem now is the data which server gets from Client2 in the starting is not transferred to Client3 by service because server keeps separate threads for clients, I guess.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238590/how-do-i-know-if-service-is-completed?/) by [Pikachu](https://answers.ros.org/users/22900/pikachu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2016-07-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-07-04**:
Step 2 does not automatically work. A server provides a service, but does not distribute data without being called from the outside. Can you either post the relevant sections of your code or, better still, link to a GitHub/whatever repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to set up some kind of communication between the clients, if I understand correctly what you want to do.

Are your clients all seperate nodes? I guess so. So you could e.g. publish a topic in the server with the state that it is in. And in the clients listen to this topic.

But I'm not quite sure what you actually intend to do with you system.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pikachu](https://answers.ros.org/users/22900/pikachu/) on 2016-07-04**:
Yes, all clients are separate nodes. I have edited the question for better understanding.